# Electron Mac App - Request System Contact Access (node-mac-permissions)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store

I am building an electron mac app and require access to the users contacts. I want the app to display a popup, similar to the one attached below.

[Popup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vamL.png)

I discovered [node-mac-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mac-permissions), and tried using it but when I run the `askForContactAccess()` function, nothing happens. According to the npm page, it says that you have to update certain values on the Info.plist file for this to work, however there is no Info.plist file to add to.

I tried creating an Info.plist file to add these values to, but this did not fix the issue. I also tried building the app using electron builder, then modifying the generated Info.plist file to include these values and this also did not resolve the issue.

Here is the code I am using

```
const { askForContactsAccess} = require("node-mac-permissions");
askForContactsAccess().then((status) => {
    console.log(`Access to Contacts is ${status}`);
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.